# ftrace not working? Probably a simple mistake

Tags: kernel, debugging, ftrace

I am trying to monitor the function `pci_bus_write_config_byte`. I have a kernel module that I know for certain calls that function.

`echo "pci_bus_write_config_byte" > set_ftrace_filter`

Then I did `cat trace_pipe` and loaded the module, but nothing is displayed on the terminal.

Am I missing something? Is there a "turn ftrace on" variable I am missing?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to turn on tracing. See my blog on [here](http://vcheru.blogspot.com/2015/08/linux-ftrace-see-underlying-semantics.html) on this topic.

```
[root@mylinux1 tracing]# pwd
/sys/kernel/debug/tracing
[root@mylinux1 tracing]# echo pci_bus_write_config_byte > set_ftrace_filter
[root@mylinux1 tracing]# echo function > current_tracer 
[root@mylinux1 tracing]# echo 1 > tracing_on
```

Checkout more detailed info on ftrace,perf at Brendan Gregg's [blog](http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2014-08-30/ftrace-the-hidden-light-switch.html)

Comment: I turned on tracing, but that didn't do anything.
`# echo SyS_read >set_graph_function ;

# echo function_graph > current_tracer ;

# echo 1 > tracing_on` 

Then I cat trace or trace_pipe, nothing is displayed out.
I am specifically trying to track the `pci_bus_write_config_byte` function, but I get the same result.

Comment: See my updated answer. You'll see any output, only when that function get's called. you can test with other simple syscalls, by echoing them into `set_ftrace_filter`

Comment: Makes sense, so I did exactly that. I'm also testing systemtap which works quite well. It seems to be the superior system, similar'ish to dtrace.

Comment: What kernel version is this? As SyS_read isn't available anymore on x86 kernels. It's now something like: __x64_sys_read. And tracing_on should be on by default unless you did something to turn it off.

Comment: same issue with me. On 5.4 LTS kernel and fed up of ftrace. The function that I am trying to trace indeed gets called because I get dmesg logs from it. But ftrace does not capture it.